# Json response with several tables(?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

How do I parse a Json response in form of:

www.extradelar.se/match

If I understand this response right, its an array of three responses, how do I parse them in this case? How do I Deserialize this into my RootObject?

Comment: What you have is not valid JSON. You're not closing the last object or the last array. If you were to replace the last `]` with `}]]` (to make it well-formed JSON), then you would have an array of 3 arrays, where each individual array contains a single object.

Comment: Oh sorry, I cut the JSON from alot of variables. But consider it a valid, with the correct brackets.
Basically, what I am wondering is, how do I Deserialize arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its due to copy paste but the json provided was not valid:

Using http://jsonlint.com/ you can validate an indent your json:

Once you indent, it is easier to look at .

The above `JSON` is array of array where each one contains an object.

It is a little odd for usual JSON, but maybe you have your own reasons.

Using libraries like [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) you can easily parse that data into C# objects.

Hope this helps

---

EDIT:

**POCO Class:**

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string match_id { get; set; }
    public string no_repick { get; set; }
    public string no_agi { get; set; }
    public string drp_itm { get; set; }
    public string no_timer { get; set; }
    public string rev_hs { get; set; }
    public string no_swap { get; set; }
    public string no_int { get; set; }
    public string alt_pick { get; set; }
    public string veto { get; set; }
    public string shuf { get; set; }
    public string no_str { get; set; }
    public string no_pups { get; set; }
    public string dup_h { get; set; }
    public string ap { get; set; }
    public string br { get; set; }
    public string em { get; set; }
    public string cas { get; set; }
    public string rs { get; set; }
    public string nl { get; set; }
    public string officl { get; set; }
    public string no_stats { get; set; }
    public string ab { get; set; }
    public string hardcore { get; set; }
    public string dev_heroes { get; set; }
    public string verified_only { get; set; }
    public string gated { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON.NET**

```
private string getMatchId()
{
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        const string url = @"http://www.extradelar.se/match"; 
        var json = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        var matchen = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<RootObject>>>(json);
        var matchId = matchen[0][0].match_id;

        return matchId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect JSON, heres the full response:
http://extradelar.se/match

Comment: @user3581054 ok, my answer stand the same unless you need me to expand on something ?

Comment: Sorry, but I cant find any documentation about parse arrays of arrays :)

Comment: @user3581054 Libraries handle it for you, such as the one meda linked to in his post. Ex: `var myobj=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`

Comment: var matchen = new RootObject();
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                string query = @"url to json";
                var json = webClient.DownloadString(query);

                var myobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, matchen);

                return matchen.match_id;
            }
This code throws me: "Additional information: Cannot populate JSON array onto type 'HoNEnemyDevelop.Model.MatchModel+RootObject'. Path '', line 1, position 1."

Comment: @mason , do you have any tip for this kind of documentation?

Comment: @user3581054 Sorry, should have pointed out in my earlier that you have to provide a type argument to that function, since it's using generics. Ex: `MatchModel match=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MatchModel>(json);`. If that doesn't work, you need to adjust the MatchModel type so that JSON.NET can convert it properly, ex, make it match the output from [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). The site that meda linked to has plenty of documentation.